# Root issues in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm trying to activate my equalizer plug-in on rhythm-box, but it keeps asking me, '' are you root?'' I tried my own password but to no avail. I'd appreciate some advice please.

Comment: did you enter your `sudo` password?

Comment: `sudo rhythmbox`, then type in your password in terminal will open it as root, but there seem to be two configurations for root and noroot.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to start the plugin? Are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo su` then enter your password
then enter `rhythmbox` see if that opens rhythmbox as root.  Let me know if it works